# Segmentation fault on PuTTY

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have an assignment from my school, which requires me to write the `c program` on PuTTY, I already finished my code, then the code was executed perfectly, the compiler doesn't complain anything, but I got a segmentation fault. Please help!

[This is the assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uHWW.png)

[These are commands which I typed from PuTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuVLr.png)

This is source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BLANK ' '
#define NEWLINE '\n'
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    FILE *infile;
    char c;
    int char_count = 0;

infile = fopen(argv[2], "r");

if(infile = NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot open %s \n", argv[0], argv[2]);
    exit(1);
}
    
while ( (c = getc(infile)) != EOF)
    if ((c != BLANK) && (c != NEWLINE) )
        char_count++;
   
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-s") == 0)
            {   
                printf ("%d characters\n", char_count);
            }
    }
    else if (argc == 4)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-f") == 0)
        {
            FILE *outfile;
            outfile = fopen(argv[3], "w");
            if(outfile == NULL)
            {
                printf("error cannot open file");
                exit(1);
            }
            fprintf (outfile, "My file has %d chars\n", char_count);
        }
    }
```

return 0;
}

Comment: Please do not post code and text output as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: Also, what debugging have you done? Run your program in a debugger and/or add debug print statements to trace the program flow and variable values. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: [Edit] your question and show all of your text ad properly formatted text, not as picctures of text,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've got typo:
`if(infile = NULL)`
which assigns `NULL` to `infile`, and `if` becomes `if (NULL)` which is never true.
after this line `infile` is `NULL`, but program continues and tries to read from `NULL` file.

the fix:
`if (infile == NULL)`